# ld: SDK.framework compiled with older version of Swift language (XX) than previous files (unknown ABI version YYY) of ObjC Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, linker

#### Intro

I working on `SDK.framework` which I need to distribute as *closed source* software. To cover both objective-c and swift projects I decided to write it on objective-c

In local environment I have two projects:

- SDK (framework source code)
- DemoApp (app which links with SDK.framework)

*These projects in separate workspace

#### Problem

When I compile `SDK.framework` locally it work perfect.

Once I get one from CI (it have different iOS SDK version) and trying to link it with `DemoApp` I getting this error:

> ld: SDK.framework compiled with older version of Swift language (4.0) than previous files (unknown ABI version 0x06)

#### Questions

1. Because my SDK 100% objective-c framework, I have no idea why it claims about swift version
2. My SDK have dependency on another frameworks and one of them is [`SocketIO-Client-Swift`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift). AFAIK this should not be related to error above, because I compile `SocketIO-Client-Swift` with `DemoApp`, so it have the same swift version as `DemoApp` app

#### What I did

1. With `otool -l SDK.framework` I checked all meta information, there is no any reference to swift
2. I have tried distribute it as static library but in this case I will have problem with support `Carthage` dependency manager

Comment: recompile it with the new Xcode version.

Comment: @JuanBoero it's not a case for me, because this is SDK which provided as a framework (binary), and according to your suggestions I will need to publish a new release for any tiny libSwift change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, this is because you are linked with Swift framework. Even your code is 100% Obj-C it contains references to Swift calls which are part of your SDK ABI.

Consider C++ version of SocketIO instead.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp